# Python statsforecast season_length vs freq

Tags: python, arima, statsforecast

When setting up statsforecast models (for example AutoARIMA), one parameter is season_length for each model, and then for the statsforecast object, there is the freq parameter.

My assumption is that if I have weekly data, but I think that seasonality is monthly, I set freq to weekly and season_length to 4, or is this so that if I set freq to monthly, and then I'd set season_length to 4 as there are 4 samples in a season.

So how do these relate?

Answer (score 0):

The `freq` parameter refers to the datestamps in your data. For example, if you have monthly data, `freq` should equal 'M'. Behind the scenes, statsforecast uses this parameter to create future dates of the output dataframe. This parameter supports the [offset aliases supported by pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases).

On the other hand, the `season_length` parameter of the models refers to the number of samples in a season. In the case of monthly data, it should equal 12.

If you have weekly data, you could use `freq='W'` and `season_length=4` (if you are considering monthly seasonality).